# Modify the foot of Item HoverPanel in Search results SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, search-results, display-template

I want to add 4 buttons to the bottom of display template **Item Default HoverPanel** for search results. I need it display like the person column with user's name and photo.
[image]

By default, it displays **Open** and **Send**. I want to change it to 4 boutons (Send message, Tel, Tel with video, Send mail)

[image]

In the display template **Item Default HoverPanel**, it has a variable value ***#= ctx.RenderFooter(ctx) =#***

[image]

I can add a button for sending an email to user. But 3 other buttons (Send message, Tel, Tel with video) I have no idea how to add.
For example, if I click the button Tel, I can call user directly, I do not need to click the phone number with phone. I don't know how to do. How could I create the same thing like the column person ?

**Update:**

I found an article which exactly meets my need, I do the same thing but the presence icon does not display. It displays nothing. And the value of **SIP address** is null
 http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/add-presence-to-sharepoint-search-results/

Is it possible that there is an error in server setting ?
Or it just works on the people search results page ? My search scope is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your english completely, but I guess you want something like that:

```
                AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){ULSaRe:;
                    EnsureScriptFunc("clienttemplates.js", "RenderUserFieldWorker", function() {ULSaRe:;
                        var getUserPersona = function() {ULSaRe:;
                            var renderCtx = new ContextInfo();
                            renderCtx.Templates = {};
                            renderCtx.Templates["Fields"] = {};
                            var fieldSchemaData = { "PictureOnly":"1", "PictureSize": "Size_72px"};
                            var listSchema = {"EffectivePresenceEnabled": "1", "PresenceAlt": Srch.Res.item_People_NoPresenceAvailable};
                            var userData = {"title": uName, "email": uEmail, "picture": uPicUrl, "sip": uSip};
                            var personaControlElement = document.getElementById(userPersonaId);
                            if (!Srch.U.n(personaControlElement))
                            {
                                personaControlElement.innerHTML = RenderUserFieldWorker(renderCtx, fieldSchemaData, userData, listSchema);
                            }
                            if(typeof(ctx.EnqueueImnRequest) == "undefined") { ctx.EnqueueImnRequest = false; }
                            if (ctx.EnqueueImnRequest == false) {
                                ctx.ClientControl.add_oneTimeResultRendered(function(){ULSaRe:; if (typeof(ProcessImn) != "undefined") { ProcessImn(); } });
                                ctx.EnqueueImnRequest = true;
                             }
                        };
                        getUserPersona();
                    });
                });
```

(this code you can find in the Display template "item_person_compactHorizontal.js").

You can Play around with Settings for fieldSchwmaData and listShema. (eg. ImnHeader: True, Variations of "DEfaultRenderer"). For this I suggest you to debug into the renderuserfieldworker method.

Comment: Could you give me more information, please ? I try this code but it does not work. Maybe I should add more ?

Answer (score 0):

Because my SIP Adress is blank. So I change it to person's email. It works !!!!
This article is very useful:
http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/add-presence-to-sharepoint-search-results/

Thank you all !!!!!